# Why iptables block my port 80 traffic?

Tags: iptables

I've setup a configuration on iptables to allow only the traffic I need. I opened the port 80... but with iptables enabled, I cannot reach my site.

This is the configuration... Where I've made some mistake?

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT  -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --sport 21 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --sport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED,NEW -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT  -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -i eth0 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -o eth0 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix BANDWIDTH_OUT:
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix BANDWIDTH_IN:
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix BANDWIDTH_OUT:
-A INPUT -i eth0 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix BANDWIDTH_IN:
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
```

Comment: Hard to tell without any context about your network interfaces and what's the role of the box where you have set them up (intermediate firewall?). But a quick look make me think you allowed forwarding from eth0 to eth1 and not the opposite so packets are blocked.

Comment: You have only 3 rules for port 80. Disable them. 1) Does it work now? Yes: enable another rule, go to 1). No: Disable another rule, go to 1)